# Fail to get real time prices from Alpha Vantage API. Prices are one day old

Tags: algorithm, trading, alpha-vantage

I am trying to get the latest Intraday prices from Alpha Vantage API. Currently it is Friday, 9:16PM Eastern European Time. I am trying to get Tesla stock. Markets are still open. However, The API call returns me yesterday's data only. What could be the problem?

```
ts = TimeSeries(key='API_KEY', output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='TSLA',interval='1min', outputsize='full')
print(data.head(5))
print(meta_data)

                     1. open  2. high   3. low  4. close  5. volume
date                                                               
2020-04-16 16:00:00   746.06  746.830  745.530  745.6800    83342.0
2020-04-16 15:59:00   746.57  746.715  745.090  746.1958    53268.0
2020-04-16 15:58:00   746.90  747.465  746.490  746.6250    36746.0
2020-04-16 15:57:00   747.52  747.760  746.827  747.2147    25910.0
2020-04-16 15:56:00   747.95  747.990  746.800  747.2800    33869.0
{'1. Information': 'Intraday (1min) open, high, low, close prices and volume', '2. Symbol': 'TSLA', '3. Last Refreshed': '2020-04-16 16:00:00', '4. Interval': '1min', '5. Output Size': 'Full size', '6. Time Zone': 'US/Eastern'}
                      1. open   2. high   3. low  4. close  5. volume       EMA
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and wasn't able to solve it yet. But in my case only some stocks are not up to date. For example 'IBM' is up to date but 'TSLA' and 'AAPL' not. I also have written an email to the technical support 2 days ago. If I ever get a response with the explanation I will write you. I have checked this not only with the python module also with the direct API call.

My code:
https://github.com/SebNik/TradingBot

Comment: okai. I see. thanks for replying! I will try to use different stocks and see what i get. Would be great to know what technical support will say

Comment: Tried with IBM and it works much better. So yeah, some problems with some type of stocks apparently

Comment: Yeah, maybe you could write an email, too. But good to know that somebody else has the same problem.

Comment: I contacted them via Slack. They sent this issue to support as well :)

Comment: Okay, but they haven't answerded yet ?

Comment: Naa not yet. Will let you know if they will

Comment: You could try a python package called [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery). I know there’s support for almost live data (minute intervals).

Comment: If you want a free Stock API, with current Stock Prices, I recommend https://finnhub.io/
https://finnhub.io/docs/api#quote

Comment: I'm also waiting for a reply from them for 2months! Highly not recommend this company.

Answer (score 4):

I also noticed this and contacted Alpha Vantage. I got this response:

> Thank you for reaching out! For Nasdaq-listed securities such as MSFT, the data is refreshed daily at 4:30pm ET on our API platform.

So looks like real-time data is not provided for Nasdaq-listed items. This could be the issue here.

Comment: Did you by chance find an alternative to alpha vantage on those stocks?

Comment: @JensCaasen they recommended https://polygon.io/stocks to me, but I haven't looked into it